# Carbon time format

Tags: php, laravel

I save the user photo with Carbon in laravel 9

```
$user->photo_verified_at = Carbon::now()->timestamp;
```

But I get this output from database:

```
Error Message : ORA-01843: not a valid month
Position      : 42
Statement     : update &quot;USERS&quot; set &quot;PHOTO_VERIFIED_AT&quot; = :p0, &quot;USERS&quot;.&quot;UPDATED_AT&quot; = :p1 where &quot;ID&quot; = :p2
Bindings      : [1672340645,2022-12-29 19:04:05,25]
```

If you a look at the data for `created_at` and `updated_at` in the database, they have the following format:

> 29/12/22 18:30:43,000000000

How is it possible to set Carbon to return in that format?

```
Carbon::now()->timestamp->format('dd/mm/yy H:i:s')
```

it returns

```
Error: Call to a member function format() on int
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine with just `Carbon::now()` or `now()` (it is a helper function calling `Carbon::now()`)

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what you are storing there, if it is a `timestamp` that is literally a number, for example, 13102321 (just a made up number from me), it is the seconds that literally passed since a known date (I think it is January 1st, 1970 or something like that).

So, if you exactly want that fomat, it is as easy as reading the documentation, it will state that you can use the normal PHP's [`Date`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) format:

```php
$formatedString = now()->format('d/m/Y H:i:s,u000');
```

You have to add 3 more `0`, as it has 9 `0`, that is nano seconds, super weird, but it is exactly the format you want...

You can also try out just using `now()` or any method that returns a literal `Carbon` object, it can or cannot work, depends how you have your model's attribute casted/declared.